# Set objMapWindow = gobjGeoApp.ActiveWindow

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0

above following command is written in VB, where objMapWindow is object,how to write same command in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these

```
dynamic objMapWindow = gobjGeoApp.ActiveWindow;

object objMapWindow = gobjGeoApp.ActiveWindow;
```